# Struts action called twice -

Tags: java, jsp, struts, request

When I submit a form to the browser,the form is submitted twice.The access log shows there are two requests arise at the same time.Two different threads executing it.

The thing is,the first request contains the attribute values that the user entered while the second request call contains only null values in request object.

Not all the times this issue occur.It happens only sometimes and not reproducible at all.Both in IE8 and IE9,I got these issues.

Do anyone know why does it happen?

Comment: are you  using ajax or submitting the form by javascript?

Comment: can you post your html <form>

Comment: if its users that cause the double request to happen check if they dont double click. Some users just always double click

Comment: I had this recently and I think @Umesh is hinting at the answer. If you use something like `document.myform.submit();` in a script that is called by a submit button then you will sometimes be hit by two submits. I seem to recall it only happened in IE and not Firefox and it only happened sometimes. To avoid, I think I used `document.myform.submit();return false;` or something like it.

Comment: @Peter I tried double-clicking.But the issue is never reproduced.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon @ UmeshAwasthi
The form is submitted only by action attribute in <form> tag not by any form.submit() in script.And I use <input type=submit> for the 'save' button.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi No ajax call or java script I use !

Comment: Is your form method GET or POST?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the problem is that you are using submit button and `document.forms[0].submit` within the javascript `onclick` event handler .

Thus action is called twice:

First time by

```
document.forms[0].submit
```

Second time by

```
submit button action
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you use struts1 or struts2? Anyway, they both have a mechanism to avoid repeat submit: **token**. 
For struts1, you need call **saveToken()** in the first action (the action for form page), and 'html:form' tag of struts will automatically add this token to your page; in your submit action (the action which dealing form), invoke **isTokenValid(request, true)**, and this will validate the token from your page & your session.

For struts2, add the interceptor ref token for your submit action, and add 's:token' tag in your form page.

The above solutions restrict repeat submitting in server side, that the second request will cause a exception and handled as invalid request. But if you wanna restrict this in UI side, you need some javascript, like: when you click the submit button, disable it to avoid repeat submitting.

Comment: Thanks Shen ! But I want to restrict it in UI side.

Comment: Yep, isTokenValid(request, true) is the key. And not isTokenValid(request).